# Python combobox with multiple columns

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, multiple-columns

I would like to know whether it is possible to create a combobox in python that uses multiple columns. A feature similar to what I am requesting is the combo box from MS Access, as those combo boxes can contain multiple columns. Does such a combo box exist in python or is there an alternative solution that I may use?

Comment: what do you mean "multiple columns" - many comboboxes next to each other? Yes, you can do it. Or one combobox with text formatted so it looks like two columns ? Yes, you can do it - you may have to use monospaced font. See example with Listox which uses monospaced font to display many columns - [listbox with many columns](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/listbox/listbox-populate-entry/main.py)

Comment: Are the multiple columns make up a table, or are you saying that instead of a long list of 100 items, you want them spread across  5 columns of 20 items each?

Comment: @BryanOakley
For example if I had 2 columns within the combo box, 1 column would contain forenames with the other column containing surnames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyqt or pyside inside python to create a QComboBox with 1 or more columns.